# how to change datepicker format in android?

Tags: android, datepicker

I have android code using datepicker. currently the output which I am getting is of the form 11-2-14. I want to get a format as 2-NOV-14.Below is a part of my current code:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
           year=c.YEAR;
            month=c.MONTH+1;
            day=c.DAY_OF_MONTH;
@Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
            case DATE_PICKER_ID1:


                // set date picker for current date 

                return new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener1, year, month,day);


           case DATE_PICKER_ID2:


                // set date picker for current date 

                return new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener2, year, month,day);


            }
            return null;
        }

        private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener1 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                    int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

                year  = selectedYear;
                month = selectedMonth;
                day   = selectedDay;

                // Show selected date 
                 date1=""+day+"-"+month+"-"+year+" ";
                Output1.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("-").append(month + 1).append("-").append(year).append(" "));



               }
            };
            private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener2 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                        int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

                    year  = selectedYear;
                    month = selectedMonth;
                    day   = selectedDay;

                    // Show selected date 
                     date2=""+day+"-"+month+"-"+year+" ";
                   Output2.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                            .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                            .append(" "));


                   }
                };
```

The above code gives the date format as 11-2-14.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, you have to swap the day with the month:

`year  = selectedYear;
 month = selectedDay;
 day   = selectedMonth;`

Then you add a private static final String array as a field in your class, where s[i] contains the string represntation of the (i - 1)th month of the year: s[10] = "NOV" and you replace

`month = selectedDay;`
with

`month = s[selectedDay];`

Answer (score 0):

Try like below code:

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                    int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

                year  = selectedYear;
                month = selectedMonth;
                day   = selectedDay;

                // Show selected date 
                 date1=""+day+"-"+month+"-"+year+" ";
                String mon = formatMonth(month+1);
                Output1.setText(day+"-"+mon+"-"+year);
               }
            };



public String formatMonth(int month) {
    Locale locale;
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM", locale);
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1);
    return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```